# How do I use orthogonal data in DataTables to sort when using HTML in a render function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

Here is a basic example to show the problem I'm facing:
http://jsfiddle.net/phb9Lms6/2/

If you click on the "Totals" column, you'll see that the sorting isn't working correctly. The problem has something to do with the fact that I've got some HTML in there (the span tags that say "current").

This is a watered down example; in reality, the number pull in from an AJAX request. But the concept is the same, and as you can see I'm using a render function to format them. Just adding the commas doesn't seem to negatively impact the sort, but as soon as I add the `<span>` tag, that's when the sorting breaks (in my `_formatStuff` function in this example).

```
$('#test_sort').dataTable({
    columns: [
        {},
        {render: _formatStuff}
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        {targets: 1, className: 'right'}
    ],
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false
});
```

I was reading about [orthogonal data](http://www.datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data) in the DataTables docs, but it's unclear to me how I would use this. Can I add some other property besides render to get it to use the original value as the sort value? Right now it seems to be using the output of [columns.render](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render), and that's obviously problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Some folks on [the DataTables forums](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23973/) led me on the right path toward the answer. I just had to use a [deprecated sorting plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/formatted-numbers) and then specify the `sType` field on the column, and that did the trick.